# Visualforce Action method does not execute in commandButton when call JQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have written a bit of code, that will disable a button in VF page once it is clicked with the help of JQuery. Unfortunately, although the button gets grayed out once clicked, my action method from the button does not get executed. Could anyone help me understand why?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[id$=submitButton]').on('click', function(){ 
            console.log( "jQuery loaded1" );
            $('input[id$=submitButton]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            console.log( "jQuery loaded2" );
         });
    });
</script>
    <apex:commandButton id="submitButton" action="{!saveConsent}" value="{!$Label.Disaster_Submit}"  styleClass="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd btn-sm">     </apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: why not use a spinner to prevent further page input and use a controller variable to disable the commandButton once the action method completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, client side code i.e. `Javascript` or `JQuery` executes before your controller code i.e. `actionMethod`.

- `JQuery/Javacript` on onclick event executes, which disables the button
- It checks for the `actionMethod` on the `commandButton` and tries to execute it.
- But as the button is disabled because of the first step, it skips calling the controller i.e. it prevents the postback from occurring.

The code which you have written is same as below, which disables the button on click using javascript. **Both the approaches would prevent the post back from happening due to the reasons mentioned above.**

```
<apex:commandButton id="submitButton" value="{!$Label.Disaster_Submit}" action="{!saveConsent}" styleClass="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd btn-sm" onclick="this.disabled=true;"/>
```

There are two approaches that can be used to prevent such kind of scenarios i.e. to prevent the same action being calling multiple times due to multiple clicks

1. **Using `actionStatus`** : Using this approach, the button can be disabled on click and user can be shown with the disabled button saying that processing is going on. Once the action is complete, the button will be enabled once again. **Note** that you need to use dummy (or any component you want to reRender) `reRender` attribute on `commandButton` for this to work properly. Also, if you are making any redirection from your `actionMethod`, then make sure that development mode of user is switched **OFF**, as this does not redirect to the page when development mode is **ON** for the user.
2. **Using `actionFunction`** : Using this approach, `actionMethod` can be called using `actionFunction` and then button can be disabled. **Note** the sequence of the code in `Javascript` method, it first calls the `actionFuction` and then disables the button. (The reason for this is explained above)

**Using actionStatus**

```
<apex:actionStatus id="buttonStatus">
   <apex:facet name="stop">
      <apex:commandButton id="submitButton" value="{!$Label.Disaster_Submit}" action="{!saveConsent}" styleClass="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd btn-sm" status="buttonStatus" reRender="dummy"/>
   </apex:facet>
   <apex:facet name="start">
     <apex:commandButton disabled="true" value="Processing..." styleClass="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd btn-sm" status="buttonStatus"/>
   </apex:facet>
 </apex:actionStatus>
```

**Using actionFunction**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableAndCallActionMethod(elementId){
        saveConsentJS();
        var submitButton = document.getElementById(elementId);
        submitButton.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
<apex:actionFunction name="saveConsentJS" action="{!saveConsent}" />
<apex:commandButton id="submitButton" value="{!$Label.Disaster_Submit}" onclick="return disableAndCallActionMethod('{!$component.submitButton');" styleClass="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd btn-sm"  > 
</apex:commandButton>
```